# Android:How can I set the AlertDialog width and height,and the button of the AlertDialog style?

Tags: android, layout, styles, android-alertdialog

I have a task to change the AlertDialog width and height by xml,I want make that become style,so I can use it easy.And that ,I need to change button of AlertDialog style also.Can you tell me a way to achieve the target。Thank you Very grateful。
PS，I'd better achieve the target by change xml。

Comment: You can have something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979369/android-activity-as-a-dialog

Comment: @ userIsAMonkey，thank you very much，I have thought about using Activity as a dialog,but  it is fiting to my task to using dialog. because there are many dialog wait to show.We want have a style to easy to show。thank you，alse。

Answer (score 18):

There are two methods 1) programatically 2) By using xml layout

```
1)=======>

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setView(layout);
builder.setTitle("Title");
alertDialog = builder.create();
alertDialog.show();
alertDialog.getWindow().setLayout(600, 400); //Controlling width and height.


                         ( or )

alertDialog.show();
WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();

lp.copyFrom(alertDialog.getWindow().getAttributes());
lp.width = 150;
lp.height = 500;
lp.x=-170;
lp.y=100;
alertDialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
```

If you want to show the layout to be displayed like `Alert dialog` see [this](http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/271)

```
2)========>
```

choose.xml

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/img"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/choose"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:layout_height="50dp"/>

<TableLayout android:id="@+id/table"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tr1" 
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="10dp">
        <ImageView 
            android:contentDescription="@string/phone"
            android:src="@drawable/phone"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/phnText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/phone"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:layout_height="50dp"/>
    </TableRow>
    <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:background="#FF000000" />

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tr2" 
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="10dp">
        <ImageView 
            android:contentDescription="@string/sms"
            android:src="@drawable/sms"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/smsText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/sms"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:layout_height="50dp"/>
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

display this as popup as like below

```
 private void showPopUp()
{
    final AlertDialog.Builder helpBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    helpBuilder.setTitle("");

    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    final View checkboxLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.choose, null);
    helpBuilder.setView(checkboxLayout);

    final AlertDialog helpDialog = helpBuilder.create();
    helpDialog.show();

    TableRow tablerowPhone  =    (TableRow)checkboxLayout.findViewById(R.id.tr1);
    TableRow tablerowSms    =    (TableRow)checkboxLayout.findViewById(R.id.tr2);

    tablerowPhone.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            helpDialog.dismiss();

            Uri callUri = Uri.parse("tel:" + listview_array[4]);  
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, callUri); 
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    tablerowSms.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            helpDialog.dismiss();

            Uri smsUri = Uri.parse("sms:" + listview_array[4]);  
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, smsUri); 
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

call this `showPopUp()` method where you want. so that you can set height and width to the layout in xml file

Comment: Thank a lot.This way can do it,but I want to do it by xml file.because I want to configure the xml to my application.do you have a way to do it by xml file? Thank you again and again。