# Custom Dialog Confusion

Tags: android, user-interface, layout

So I'm making a game where people can buy stock in hotel chains as they grow.
I needed a special dialog box who's content changes dynamically as the game progresses so I'm creating a custom dialog from scratch using AlertDialog as the foundation.

My questions are these:

1. I've tried adjusting the LinearLayout.LayoutParams for a larger width using the dialogContainer layout. For some reason, is has 0 effect on the size of the dialog box. Kinda strange. Any ideas what's causing that? I need a way to keep the height and width fixed because I want the content to eventually scroll.
2. (Removed for other question)

Here's what I've got for code so far:

```
public void buyStock(View view){

    Player thisPlayer = players[getPlayerIndexByPlayOrder(CURRENT_TURN)];
    Context context = getApplicationContext();

    //generate content for dialog       
    LinearLayout dialogContainer = new LinearLayout(context);
    dialogContainer.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(400, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1);
    dialogContainer.setLayoutParams(params);

    //title
    TextView dialogTitle = new TextView(context);
    dialogTitle.setText("Buy Stock:");
    dialogTitle.setHeight(40);
    dialogTitle.setWidth(600);

    //each hotel stock options

    //Text Content
    Hotel testHotel = new Hotel("Tower", 0);
    testHotel.setPrice(200);
    View stockPicker = getStockPicker(testHotel);


    dialogContainer.addView(dialogTitle);
    dialogContainer.addView(stockPicker);

    AlertDialog.Builder buyStockDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    buyStockDialog.setView(dialogContainer);

    buyStockDialog.show();

}

public View getStockPicker(Hotel hotel){
    Context context = getApplicationContext();


    LinearLayout container = new LinearLayout(context);
    container.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

    //Example color tile : image
    ImageView tileBlock = new ImageView(context);
    tileBlock.setBackgroundResource(tileResourceByHotel(hotel));


    //Hotel Name
    TextView hotelName = new TextView(context);
    hotelName.setText(hotel.getName());


    //Hotel Price
    TextView hotelPrice = new TextView(context);
    hotelPrice.setText("$" + hotel.getPrice());


    //"Number-Picker"
    LinearLayout numPicker = new LinearLayout(context);
    numPicker.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, 400);
    numPicker.setLayoutParams(params);
    int textValue = 0;

        //Up button
        ImageView upArrow = new ImageView(context);
        upArrow.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arrow_up);

        //text
        TextView pickerNum = new TextView(context);
        pickerNum.setText(String.valueOf(textValue));           

        //down
        ImageView downArrow = new ImageView(context);
        upArrow.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arrow_down);

    numPicker.addView(upArrow);
    numPicker.addView(pickerNum);
    numPicker.addView(downArrow);

    container.addView(tileBlock);
    container.addView(hotelName);
    container.addView(hotelPrice);
    container.addView(numPicker);

    return container;
}
enter code here
```

PLEASE NOTE: I has every intention of using Linear Layouts wherever possible simply because I come from a web development background and am very proficient using **div** tags. (Essentially a linear layout).

Answer (score 0):

To set exact size of dialog, You should use [WindowManager.LayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html) for dialog window, because framework itself defines default sizes for it.
There's lot of the similar questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11856550/androidhow-can-i-set-the-alertdialog-width-and-height-and-the-button-of-the-ale) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6922903/657487).

Basically, You can add the following call after `show()`:

```
AlertDialog dialog = buyStockDialog.show();

dialog.getWindow().setLayout(600, 400);
```

Comment: There appears to be something wrong here. getWindow() is not a valid method for the AlertDialog.Builder class. It's expecting me to TypeCast buyStockDialog which it can't. Any other ideas?