# How to fix dialog's size in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-dialog

I used Dialog feature of android to read login information.  It is working perfect, but login dialog shows different display size in different phone.  How to fix same size for all devices.

image as shows below

[image]

[image]

How to solve this problem ?

thanks in advance

Comment: u need set height and width to dialog box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by either by giving parameter at run time or creating custom dialog.
Please check this [Android:How can I set the AlertDialog width and height,and the button of the AlertDialog style?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11856550/androidhow-can-i-set-the-alertdialog-width-and-height-and-the-button-of-the-ale)

Answer (score 2):

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setView(layout);
builder.setTitle("Title");
alertDialog = builder.create();
alertDialog.show();
alertDialog.getWindow().setLayout(600, 400); //Controlling width and height.
```

**or**

```
alertDialog.show();
WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();

lp.copyFrom(alertDialog.getWindow().getAttributes());
lp.width = 150;
lp.height = 500;
lp.x=-170;
lp.y=100;
alertDialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
```